# Adding partial view within partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, recursion, partial-views

I am currently working with MVC4. In my Database I have a table called Categories with a recursive relationship to ParentCategory. Now I want the User to be able to choose a Category, a Sub-category, a Sub-Sub-Category... and so on. 
How can I add Partial Views dynamically by the result of another?
Displaying and evaluating a single Partial View is no problem.
What I currently have is:
View:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#CategoryDropDown').change(function () {
   var CategoryId = $("#CategoryDropDown").val();
   $("#CascadingCategories").load('@(Url.Action("CategoryIndexChanged", "Database", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?CategoryId=' + CategoryId);
   });
});
</script>

    <!-- random markup -->

<div id="CascadingCategories">
 <p>
   <span style="width:150px; display:inline-block; line-height:42px;">Category:</span>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCascadingCategoryDropDown", Model);}   
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryDropDown", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryDescription"), "Select a Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CategoryIndexChanged(int? CategoryId)
{
    SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
    model.GetCategoryDropDownItems(CategoryId ?? 0);
    return PartialView("__PartialCascadingCategoryDropDown", model);
}
```

My idea was now to call the partial view recursive like:

```
<!-- this will ofc result in an infinite loop-->@{//Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCascadingCategoryDropDown", Model);}}
```

, but only as soon as the predecendant list has changed.

Some thoughts and problems:

- the DropDownList will always have the same name which will make it hard to read it out
- it's not best practice to add javascript to the partial view
- Because I want to stay flexible over years I dislike the approach to simply add like 5 or 10 fields for RootCategoryDropDown, FirstLevelCategoryDropDown, SecondLevelCategoryDropDown, and so on.

What would help me:

- a possibility to check within the view whether the selected category has children
- any idea that takes a completely different approach
- any idea on how to ADD (not load) a partial view dynamically.

Thx in advance!

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery. [Refer this example of cascading dropdownlists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: Thanks, but can you maybe get a little bit more concrete on where to use jquery?. Because in difference to your answer over there, I also want to create the DropDowns dynamically as the number of necessary DropDowns can differ.

Comment: Instead of returning json and updating the options of existing dropdownlist, just return a partial view containing the dropdownlist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553286/asp-net-mvc-4-generating-a-treeview-with-recursive-partial-view <- This is the approach

Comment: Stephen: So instead of
 `$("#CascadingCategories").load('@(Url.Action("CategoryIndexChanged", "Database", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?CategoryId=' + CategoryId);`
  I create a new div containing a DropDownList and call the same method again on that new div?

Comment: Razvan: thanks, but in your example all necessary are Items are well known before. In my example the following DropDowns depend on the user actions what makes it impossible to use a simple foreach.

Comment: @Asator, Thats one option (i.e. dynamically create a new `<select>` element in the script, then call the controller to populate it)